# How to erase personal data from an iPad with dead battery?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'd like to recycle iPad 1. How do I clean all personal info?
The battery is dead, I tried to recharge it for an hour.

Comment: If it won't charge then you have two choices, replace the battery or physically destroy it, cut it in half. drill holes in it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Steve. Destroying it seems easier.

Answer (score 1):

open the ipad and smash the motherboard.
dissasembly instructions online at ifixit.com.

they can't recycle circuit boards anyway!

Comment: If you're going to go through the trouble of disassembling the iPad, why not do the job right and *replace* the battery?  This seems awfully shortsighted to destroy it.

Comment: because if op wants to recycle it, why pay for a new battery? It's just going to get scrapped.

Comment: Yes, Neuron. Makes sense. I will destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use a 2.1amp/5V charger or the iPad won't recognize the charger at all..
My old original iPad is picky about its power supply, whereas the cube and computer only produce 1amp/5V and won't work for actual charging.